# "resource temporarily unavailable" for socket connect via OpenSSL

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, openssl

I'm creating a TCP SSL connection using the OpenSSL code at the bottom.

Occasionally `BIO_do_connect()` fails and `strerror(errno)` returns:

```
Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Is there anything better I can do to avoid or handle this problem/wait and re-try with success?

Should I poll `::select()` before calling `BIO_do_connect()`?

Code:

```
SSL_library_init();

SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());

assert(ctx != NULL);

BIO* bio = BIO_new_ssl_connect(ctx);

BIO_get_ssl(bio, &ssl);
SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, host.c_str());

BIO_set_conn_hostname(bio, std::string(host + ":" + std::to_string(port)).c_str());

while(true)
{
    const int res = BIO_do_connect(bio);

    if(res > 0)
    {
        // success
        break;
    }

    // sleep, try again?
}
```

Comment: Can you try replacing `SSLv23_client_method()` with `SSLv3_client_method()` and see if it makes the problem go away?  In my experience the `SSLv23_*()` methods are a bit problematic, and if you don't absolutely need the additional backwards compatibility they provide, they are better avoided.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Will do. I will also try and get the correct SSL error string. Didn't have that at the time. So you don't think I need to poll  `select()` before calling `BIO_do_connect()`?

Comment: I think as long as you are certain that everything is set to use blocking I/O, you shouldn't need to play games with `select()`.

Comment: You should not call `strerror(errno)` but ERR_get_error etc (or simply ERR_print_errors). errno gives you only what happens internally at the socket level. But the real problems might be during the TLS handshake.